# How can I "diff" two cacerts files?

Tags: java, diff, keytool, cacerts

I have two Tomcat servers, with different "cacerts" files.  On one, running "keytool -list -keystore cacerts" says my keystore contains 95 entries, on the other, it says 96.  I tried saving the list outputs and running diff against them, but the certificates seem to be in different orders.  Before I write something, is there an intelligent utility to tell me the differences between the files?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sort`:

```
user@host1$ keytool -list -keystore cacerts | sort > certs1
user@host2$ keytool -list -keystore cacerts | sort > certs2
```

then copy both files to a single host and diff:

```
diff certs1 certs2
```